# Spring 3 MVC: App with out of annotations but using XML instead

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to develop application with spring 3 MVC not using annotations.
I have several reasons for it (I like central configuration place, I do not want to put HTTP-specific info in my controller, I do like XML files and my IDE (intellij IDEA) has good support for it).

At first, I need URL-TO-Controller mapping. It can be achieved using `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`. Although this method was eliminated from 3.0 documentation ("obsoleted by annotations") but it still works.

Then I need to map GET parameters to some bean with properties. In struts they have it by default:(
I can use `BaseCommandController`. It is deprecated but I can use `@SuppressWarnings` to get rid of ugly message.
`bindAndValidate` will populate command object after it.

At least I need to map path variables (from uri templates) to make my URLs readable.
And I am lost here.
Look: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5757

`BaseCommandController` works only with GET/POST.
I can fetch map from request using `UriTemplate`. But `bindAndValidate` accepts `HttpServletRequest` and I cannot add parameters to it: map is read-only. I can decorate it but... too many hacks!

Too many hacks for so simple needs. Hacks, deprecated classes and `BaseCommandController` which is undocumented in 3.0.

Is it possible to make app using spring mvc 3.0 w/o of annotations?
Or I should use something else (like struts-2) for MVC?

Comment: I don't see how using xml for everything makes it simpler comparing to annotations which does all the job for you. You can use `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to map url to controller.

Comment: This seems like going backwards.  In fact, the momentum in Spring is to move to less XML, not more.  The less XML there is, the simpler it is for you to look at your code and see what its doing.  Once I set up my basic XML config in my Spring projects, I rarely look at it going forward.